# Tried migrating the app from java 8 to 11 and tomcat 7 to 8 getting below errors

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, java-11

this is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xyz.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>EvalServ</artifactId>
    <version>1.27.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
        <checkstyle.version>8.44</checkstyle.version>
        <evalserv.checkstyle.fail>false</evalserv.checkstyle.fail>
        <error_prone_core.version>2.3.1</error_prone_core.version>
        <plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone.version>2.8.3</plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone.version>
        <auto-value.version>1.6</auto-value.version>
        <dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>1.4.13</dockerfile-maven-plugin.version>
      
        <dockerfile.push.skip>true</dockerfile.push.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jeval</groupId>
            <artifactId>jeval</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Swagger dependencies starts here-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Swagger dependencies ends here-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.700</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Test dependencies starts here-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Test dependencies ends here-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>evalserv</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
                        <path>/</path>
                        <ignorePackaging>true</ignorePackaging>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <!--
                            Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                            is passed as VM argument when Maven the Failsafe plugin is executed.
                        -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                                <!--
                                    Sets the name of the property containing the settings
                                    for JaCoCo runtime agent.
                                -->
                                <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <!--
                            Ensures that the code coverage report for integration tests after
                            integration tests have been run.
                        -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-integration-test</id>
                            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                                <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/integrationtests/**</include>
                        </includes>
                        <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                        <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <tomcat.port>${tomcat.port}</tomcat.port>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <argLine>${failsafeArgLine}</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                            <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>validate</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                <failOnViolation>${evalserv.checkstyle.fail}</failOnViolation>
                                <!-- Source and test directories explicitly  -->
                                <!-- specified to keep checkstyle from       -->
                                <!-- running against generated sources.      -->
                                <sourceDirectories>
                                    <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                                </sourceDirectories>
                                <testSourceDirectories>
                                    <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
                                </testSourceDirectories>
                                <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                                <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <release>11</release>
                        <verbose>false</verbose>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <compilerArgs>
                            <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                            <arg>-g</arg>
                            <arg>-parameters</arg>
                        </compilerArgs>
                        <annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <path>
                                <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
                                <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
                                <version>${auto-value.version}</version>
                            </path>
                        </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone</artifactId>
                            <version>${plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <!-- override plexus-compiler-javac-errorprone's dependency on
                             Error Prone with the latest version -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                            <version>${error_prone_core.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${dockerfile-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>verifying</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                                <goal>push</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <repository>${docker.registry.url}</repository>
                        <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                        <buildArgs>
                            <WAR_FILE>evalserv.war</WAR_FILE>
                        </buildArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am getting below error

```
 <p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
 <p><b>Message</b> Servlet.init() for servlet [Expressions] threw exception</p>
 <p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
 </p>
 <p><b>Exception</b></p>
 <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Expressions] threw exception
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.base&#47;java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
</pre>
 <p><b>Root Cause</b></p>
 <pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.&lt;init&gt;(ClassReader.java:171)
 jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.&lt;init&gt;(ClassReader.java:153)
 jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.&lt;init&gt;(ClassReader.java:425)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:915)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:869)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:775)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:1206)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.&lt;init&gt;(ResourceConfig.java:1178)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1174)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.&lt;init&gt;(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.&lt;init&gt;(WebComponent.java:392)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
 org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
 javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:367)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:639)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:882)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1647)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.base&#47;java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
</pre>
 <p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.</p>
 <hr class="line" />
 <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.79</h3>
```

Lots of people suggested it is because of older version of jersey, but I couldn't find a way to upgrade it, I am using **swagger-jersey2-jaxrs** dependency and it is already latest version. Please help me with this
I have encountered this problem while migrating my app from java 8 to java 11

This is web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >


<web-app>
    <display-name>EvalServ</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>version</param-name>
        <param-value>${version}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>configFileName</param-name>
        <param-value>/default.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.freshworks.platforms.api.v1.evalserv.configs.ConfigLoader</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Expressions</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                io.swagger.jaxrs.listing;
                com.freshworks.platforms.api.v1.evalserv.controllers;
                com.freshworks.platforms.api.v1.evalserv.errors;
                com.freshworks.platforms.api.v1.evalserv.filter;
                org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.xyz.abc.api.v1.evalserv.filter.JsonParseExceptionFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>io.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>api.version</param-name>
            <param-value>1.27.0</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
            <param-value>/evalserv/api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Expressions</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Update**: Using java-servelt-api 3.1.0 version as recommended here (https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Comment: I assume the issue is more with the Servlet API vs. Tomcat versions. Try matching it from this site https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: Which version of Jersey are you using exactly?

Comment: Hi @GopinathRadhakrishnan Thanks for sharing the link, As you have suggested I have changed the javax.servlet-api version to 3.1.0 but I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @Olivier I am using swagger-jersey2-jaxrs dependency which will pull specific version of jersey 2.x.x

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude unwanted version using below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>           
        </dependency>
```

then include new dependency with version you need.